# Magento 1.4.2 not displaying/saving product images on frontend & backend

Tags: image, magento, show, frontend, backend

My Magento 1.4.2 site suddenly developed the following problem:

When uploading product images, the images appear to have successfully uploaded & are visible when I rollover the image but as soon as I save the image 'disappears' and is not saved to the media subfolder. Hence it is not displayed. The permissions on the folders are set to writeable. I have cleared the cache; re-indexed stock-status, product flat data...; renamed media/.htaccess; renamed php.ini.sample to php.ini & changed memory_limit from 64M to 512M.

The problem persists. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error message when saving the product in the admin? What do you see in the frontend page? a broken image link?

Comment: Have you tried disabling extensions?

Comment: Do you have enough free disc space?

Comment: @Joy If your problem is fixed , Please share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you've updated Prototype to version 1.7? If so, you'll have to [change `foo.toJSON()` calls in *js/mage/adminhtml/product.js* to `Object.toJSON(foo)`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/4348/P45/#t327010).